# Графический интерфейс для обрезки изображений на Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброго времени суток.

Возникла необходимость написать приложение с GUI, которое позволяло бы выбирать на фотографии область и обрезать ее по этой области. Сама область должна иметь форму круга, должна быть возможность изменять размеры этого круга. Есть ли готовые решения для моей проблемы? Либо какими средствами это реализовывается? Раньше ни с чем подобным не работал

**UPD:**
Также должна быть возможность перетаскивать круг с помощью мыши

Comment: Сомневаюсь что есть готовые решения. А вы сами как себе представляете изменение размеров круга? Можно колесом мыши, например, или по кнопке на клавиатуре, например +/- на NumPad

Comment: @АндрейNOP в идеале - брать за край и растягивать/уменьшать, как это делается обычно, но вариант с колесиком мыши тоже подойдет.

Comment: С колесиком, думаю, будет меньше заморочек. Пробуйте...

Comment: @АндрейNOP в плане заморочек - да. А что пробовать? Я как раз и спрашиваю, какими средствами это реализовать?

Comment: Было бы WPF - я бы подсказал :) Видимо придется рисовать/перерисовывать эллипс "вручную"

Comment: @АндрейNOP с WPF не работал, но готов выслушать варианты решения моей задачи на этой платформе)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Готовое приложение. Изучайте.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        PictureBox pictureboxTarget;
        PictureBox pictureBoxSource;
        int size = 100;

        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();

            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

            pictureBoxSource = new PictureBox { Parent = this };
            pictureBoxSource.Load("pic.png");
            pictureBoxSource.Size = pictureBoxSource.Image.Size;

            pictureBoxSource.Paint += PictureBox_Paint; ;
            pictureBoxSource.MouseWheel += PictureBox_MouseWheel;
            pictureBoxSource.MouseMove += PictureBox_MouseMove;
            pictureBoxSource.MouseClick += PictureBox_MouseClick;

            pictureboxTarget = new PictureBox { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Right };
        }

        private void PictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var sourceImage = (Bitmap)pictureBoxSource.Image;
            var targetImage = new Bitmap(size, size, sourceImage.PixelFormat);

            var point = pictureBoxSource.PointToClient(MousePosition);
            var delta = size / 2;

            var srcRect = new Rectangle(point.X - delta, point.Y - delta, size, size);
            var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, size, size);

            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(targetImage))
            using (var path = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                path.AddEllipse(destRect);
                g.SetClip(path);

                g.DrawImage(sourceImage, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                pictureboxTarget.Size = targetImage.Size;
                pictureboxTarget.Image?.Dispose();
                pictureboxTarget.Image = targetImage;

                targetImage.Save("cropped.png", ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }

        private void PictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBoxSource.Refresh();
        }

        private void PictureBox_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            size += e.Delta / 10;

            if (size < 10)
                size = 10;
            else if (size > pictureBoxSource.Width)
                size = pictureBoxSource.Width;

            pictureBoxSource.Refresh();
        }

        private void PictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var point = pictureBoxSource.PointToClient(MousePosition);
            var delta = size / 2;
            var pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            pen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot;
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, point.X - delta, point.Y - delta, size, size);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Событие MouseWheel почему-то не срабатывает